# Javascript Error handling : How to differentiate between custom errors and reference errors etc based on their data structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

When making api requests, if its a custom error thrown by me, the structure will be ((for the message)

> err.response.data.message
> If. its a reference error for example it will be
> err.message

I only want to pass along and display the custom err messages of course and for now I always do this check:

`const error = err.message ? GENERIC_ERROR : err.response.data.message;`

I dont think thats good or very reliable. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks

Comment: So you want `err instanceof Error ? `

Comment: Thanks. I cannot do that because for my custom errors I extend Error : class BaseError extends Error {} so for custom errors it would also result to true

Comment: Then you should probably check `err instanceof BaseError` and reverse the other parts of the ternary.

Comment: I define BaseError on the backend, how can I refer to it and check it on the client side?